# Copy a directory with special character

Tags: windows, directory, file-copy

I have directory on my **External hard disk** with name like this **$recycle.bin** which was copied from a PC running windows OS.This folder was hidden on windows PC and is still invisible on my computer . Now i wanted to copy this folder on my computer via command prompt so that i can make it visible , however when i copy the same via command prompt it says directory not found

Answer (score 1):

`$recycle.bin` is the windows trashcan.  It is a directory.

Now `$` is a special character for the shell and it will try to expand the variable `$recycle`, which you did not set anywhere.

So when you try to `cp -r $recycle.bin somewhere/else/` the shell will expand this to `cp -r .bin somewhere/else`.  So unless there is a `.bin`-directory, nothing will be copied.

If you really need this directory, you need to escape the special character:

`cp -r \$recycle.bin somewhere/else/`.